# What are the fundamental sauces that every cook should know how to make?

Tags: sauce

I'd like to learn to make some sauces and I'm looking for the most common, "standard" sauces that professional cooks all learn how to make in culinary school.

What sauces form the basic "building blocks" of cooking and how are they prepared?

Comment: Voting to close because there is no objective answer possible. (Though it is an interesting question, just not within the guidelines of this forum.)

Comment: I actually see this having some benefit as a community wiki question. There are a somewhat discrete number of "common" sauces to answer with. The mother sauces are prime candidates.

Comment: I've converted this question to Community Wiki. Questions that are asking for polls or multiple correct answers are best added as community wiki.

Comment: Better to rephrase it for specificity, i.e. "What are the five mother sauces in French cooking, and briefly how do you make them.  Or, how to you make a basic pan sauce?  As of now it's in that gray area between a completable list and an open call for favorite sauces, either of which would yield some good answers.

Comment: I think it's worth keeping this one open.  But I also agree that the question itself needs a little work to prevent this from devolving into a giant list of sauce recipes.  It's more than just the "mother sauces" but perhaps something like, *"what are the standard sauces that every professional cook must be trained in making?"*  Any thoughts?

Comment: Ah, community wiki makes sense (to the degree I understand it, which I don't - I've asked a question over on meta). I'd remove my vote to close but apparently that isn't possible.

Comment: @Everyone:  Nice edits.  I like this question better than the one I asked :)

Comment: I assume you mean western european cooking school? I don't see anything asian, african, etc here. It's purely French and Italian.

I'd like to see a generic BBQ sauce recipe :) Life isn't complete without burnt meat.

Comment: As there's no 'right answer' to this, and this is likely to be lists, I'm going to be make this 'community wiki'

Comment: @Joe - what about http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/913/what-is-community-wiki?

Comment: Doesn't matter anyway, since it's a dupe.  The old question is kind of grandfathered, I guess.  And we reworked that one to be a little more specific.

Answer (score 13):

The next answer is a simple pan sauce.

After sauteing a protein in a pan, there are caramelized bits of fat, spice, and flesh that make for a great sauce base.

Getting those bits into a sauce takes a little work, but it's easily accomplished by adding an acidic liquid to the pan and allowing it to *deglaze*, or breakdown the fatty bits into the sauce.

You can deglaze with red or white wine, stock and lemon juice, or alcohol (be careful if it's high proof, since it will flame).  After adding the acid, stir to break up the bits and let simmer for long enough to reduce the liquid about 30 to 50 %, longer for thicker sauces.

Then add fat, either butter, oil, or cream, and whatever seasonings (tomato paste, mustard, Worcestershire sauce, etc. you want in the sauce). Simmer for just long enough to incorporate the ingredient (1-2 minutes max).

This is a good technique because it can work with any pan-cooked dish and whatever ingredients you have around.

The basic steps are the same, but the results are varied and quite tasty.

Comment: Start with a few versions suggested by a cookbook or someone who already knows what they are doing, but once you get the hang of this it is easy to ad lib: hmmm...I have galleano and cloves, that might work.

Answer (score 11):

The five best candidates would have to be [five mother sauces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother_sauce#Sauces_in_French_cuisine) of French cuisine.

These are:

- Béchamel
- Espagnole
- Velouté
- Tomate (similar, but not to be confused with Italian tomato-based sauces)
- Hollandaise

Any *chef* should know these. These form the basis of many other French sauces. Some of the more well known include Béarnaise, Mayonnaise, Mornay, and Tartar.

From there you can really expand almost endlessly. Some of the most well known Italian sauces such as Puttanesca, Bolognese, Pesto, Marinara, and Vodka sauce should be required knowledge as well.

I suggest reading up on [sauces on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sauce), there are lots of examples there.

Comment: Dammit. I only had my answer half typed out, and I was still working out how to make the e with the diacritical mark. The *grandes sauces*, the mother sauces, are critical. They're the root of every sauce you'll ever want to make (in western cooking).

Comment: @Satanicpuppy: :( It's a pain, I cut and pasted it from a word on wikipedia.

Comment: All cooking is not French cooking. Not that these are bad things to know, but...

Comment: @satanicpuppy : If you're a Mac user, hit opt-e, then the letter you want.  The other marks are attached to other vowels for the most part, but there's a few exceptions.  (and some aren't modifiers; e:é; u:ü; i:î; `:è; o:ø; a:å; n:ñ)

Comment: @Joe: wtf. I'm a mac user and I didn't know that. Where did you find that out?

Comment: You just learn these things when your name has non-ascii characters in it.  There used to be a thing called 'Key Caps' in the days before MacOS X (since at least System 6).  It's now harder to find : http://support.apple.com/kb/TA22403?viewlocale=en_US  (I'm still on 10.4, so can't verify if it's still there on 10.5 / 10.6).  But it's useful when you're teaching a computing class, and you want the class to see what you're typing).  Or when you're trying to use a wingdings/dingbats type font.

Comment: I've been to Italy quite a few times, and eaten everywhere from very excepensive restaurants down to piaza cafes and never seen vodka sauce.

Living in New York, it's hard to miss it.

Also, bolognese is normally ragu on a true italian menu.

Comment: @Alex: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vodka_sauce

Comment: @hobo - the last time I checked that article it was still saying it was invented in NYC. Times change.

And I've still never seen it outside of NYC/NorthEast US.

Comment: @Alex: Interesting. I've read that it didn't really catch on in Italy, but took off here. I have seen it on both coasts as well as the midwest. I've never eaten Italian outside of the US though, because I've never been to Italy.

Answer (score 11):

I think even more important than learning the mother sauces (though they certainly have plenty to teach), is learning the underlying fundamentals on both a culinary and scientific level. You need to be able to envision how you want a sauce to taste, feel, look and smell (not so worried about hearing) and then translate that into ingredients and execution.

Needless to say this is a lifelong study.

Here's an example of what I mean. I can think of three major ways of thickening a sauce. I'm probably forgetting some. (1) emulsification, such as happens in a vinaigrette, hollandaise, or mayonnaise, in which droplets of one liquid get surrounded by another that can't dissolve it. (2) starches/colloids which interfere with the flow of liquid, such as cornstarch, flour, arrowroot, or all sorts of fun engineered starches (3) reduction - simmering out some of the water so the solids are a higher percentage of the volume.

Each of these methods has pluses and minuses. For example, reduction avoids adding any undesirable starchiness or diluting flavors to the sauce, but requires prolonged cooking or high heat which may change the flavors for better or worse.

I could go on an on! But the point I'm driving at is, instead of trying to memorize a few sauces, you'll do yourself more good in the long run by learning the principles that they rely on so you are free to create and adapt (and fix when things go wrong).

Answer (score 7):

There are 5 French "mother sauces":

- Bechamel - milk, thickened with a roux
- Veloute - light stock, thickened with a light roux
- Tomato
- Espagnole - brown stock, thickened with a brown roux
- Hollandaise - an emulsification of eggs and butter

They're called "mother sauces" because most (all?) other sauces in French cooking are derived from these basic sauces. Learning the technique for a roux is a critical first step in making most sauces.

Answer (score 2):

After the ones that Bob mentioned, other 'worth knowing how to make by memory' are basic proportions and techniques for for :

- pan sauces  (ie, deglaze the pan, reduce, maybe add some butter)
- mayonaise
- pesto

(and for the most part, 'brown gravy' is a veloute, 'white gravy' is a bechamel, although the fat used for the roux would change)